# Web form upload same data twice in database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am uploading data to databases but my form upload the same data twice in databases first I was uploading data without checking weather is inserted or not it was working fine it was uploading the data single time now I have put the checked that if data inserted than show the message data inserted successful but this is uploading data twice.

Here is my code:

```
SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ZAZIKHAN\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=resume;Integrated Security=True");
conn1.Open();

SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("insert into Profile(Id,Name,JobTitle,Phone,Email,Address,Website,Facebook,Twitter,GooglePlus,Skype,Picture,WhyMeText) values('"+ID.Text+"','" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + "','" + TextBox4.Text + "','" + TextBox5.Text + "','" + TextBox6.Text + "','" + TextBox7.Text + "','" + TextBox8.Text + "','" + TextBox9.Text + "','" + TextBox10.Text + "','" + uploadFolderPath + "','" + TextArea1.InnerText + "')", conn1);

cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
if (cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
{
        Response.Write("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript' >alert('information saved Successful')</script>");
        TextBox1.Text = "";
        TextBox2.Text = "";
        TextBox3.Text = "";
        TextBox4.Text = "";
        TextBox5.Text = "";
        TextBox6.Text = "";
        TextBox7.Text = "";
        TextBox8.Text = "";
        TextBox9.Text = "";
        TextBox10.Text = "";
        TextArea1.InnerText = "";
}
else { Response.Write("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript' >alert('sorry try again')</script>"); }

conn1.Close();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because you execute your `SqlCommand` twice.

One is with

```
cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

And the other one is with;

```
if (cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
```

From [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

> **Executes** a Transact-SQL statement against the connection and returns
>   the number of rows affected.

And please always use [`parameterized queries`](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html). This kind of string concatenations are open for [`SQL Injection`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Also use [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement to dispose your `SqlConnection` like;

```
using(SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ZAZIKHAN\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=resume;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    //Write here your command with parameterized way..
    conn1.Open();
    if (cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
    {
      //....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the first `cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();` and it will work fine

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get boolean result, perfom this one :

```
  bool result = Convert.ToBoolean(cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery());
  if(result)
   {
      //Rest of function
   }
```